# need a regex for 3 types of input

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to get a regex which allows only input containing:

[1. positive digit, 2. whitespace, 3. negative digit]

for example

```
1 -2
234 -453
3454 -2
```

I tried

```
    input.matches("\\d+\\s\\d+")
```

but i think it only allows positive numbers and I just cannot come up with condition for negative numbers.

Comment: Well... how do you identify a negative number?

Comment: How would you want to handle -0, btw? Is that acceptable as a positive number? A negative?

Comment: I do not need 0 i think... but if you know how to do it with 0 then i could implement it aswell

Comment: @f1sh hmm i mean just something with a minus in front of it?

Comment: @lolzie what does a negative number start with?

Comment: soo "\\d+\\s\\d-" should work?

Comment: @lolzie try it. But then think about why that doesn't work.

Comment: @lolzie why whould there a minus sign at the end?

Comment: Try with `\\d+\\s-\\d+`

Comment: Okay I got it, i mean i just learned yesterday about these regexes and I am still very new to coding, that's why i sometimes make silly stuff, but yeah fix was pretty easy i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you?

```
[0-9]+ -[0-9]+
```

The second expression is waiting a number followed by dash.